# PHP: Building an array of dates with two types of sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of appointments that I need to order in a special way. Let's say the current date is 30 May 2016 and the current time is 11:00h:

```
$currentTimestamp = strtotime("05/30/2016 11:00");
// results in 1464620400
```

First, here comes the array of appointments which contains timestamps for the end of each appointment:

```
$allDates = [
'2016-05-24' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464086700

    ]
],
'2016-05-27' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464349500
    ]
],
'2016-05-30' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464606900

    ],
    [
        'end' => 1464614100
    ],
    [
        'end' => 1464623100
    ]
],
'2016-05-31' => [
    [
        'ende' => 1464705900
    ]
]
```

];

Here come the requirements for resorting this array:

- All appointments whose end is later than the current timestamp must be ordered descending.
- All appointments whose end is earlier than the current timestamp must be ordered ascending.

My desired output is the following:

```
$desiredFinalArrDates = [
'2016-05-31' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464705900
    ]
],
'2016-05-30' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464623100
    ]
],
// !!! past dates start from here, ascending...
 '2016-05-24' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464086700

    ]
],
'2016-05-27' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464349500
    ]
],
 '2016-05-30' => [
    [          
        'end' => 1464606900
    ],
    [
        'end' => 1464614100
    ]
 ] 
];
```

How do I achieve the desired ordering of my $allDates array?

*-------------- My attempt so far ----------------*

```
$future = [];
$past = [];

foreach ($allDates as $key => $subarr) {
    foreach ($subarr as $value) {
        if ($value['end'] >= $currentTimestamp) {
            $future[$key][] = $value;
        } else {
            $past[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
}

asort($past);

$desiredFinalArrDates  = array_merge($future, $past);
```

The problem is that with array_merge my keys get overwritten.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too

Comment: You can't have same key multiple times within array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance doesn't matter, you can do it like this.

```
1. create two arrays $arrBefore and $arrAfter. 
2. Then iterate the $allDates array (and all sub-arrays) and compare the current value with $currentTimestamp. 
3. If lower add it to the $arrBefore array, else to the $arrAfter. 
4. Then sort the arrays correspondigly (descending/ascending). 
5. Finally, merge this two arrays.
```

EDIT:
This will create two arrays `$arrBefore and $arrAfter` which are sorted correctly. To achieve your desired output, is not possible in that form. That's because you can't have the same key multiple times in an array (i.e. `2016-05-30` in your case).

```
<?php


$currentTimestamp = strtotime("05/30/2016 11:00");

$allDates = [
'2016-05-24' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464086700

    ]
],
'2016-05-27' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464349500
    ]
],
'2016-05-30' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464606900

    ],
    [
        'end' => 1464614100
    ],
    [
        'end' => 1464623100
    ]
],
'2016-05-31' => [
    [
        'end' => 1464705900
    ]
]
    ];

$arrBefore = array();
$arrAfter = array();

foreach($allDates as $currKey => $currDateArr){
    foreach($currDateArr as  $currDate){

        if($currDate['end'] < $currentTimestamp){
            if(array_key_exists($currKey,$arrBefore)){
                $arrBefore[$currKey][] = $currDate['end'];          
            }else{
                $arrBefore[$currKey] = array($currDate['end']);
            }
        }else{
            if(array_key_exists($currKey,$arrAfter)){
                $arrAfter[$currKey][] = $currDate['end'];           
            }else{
                $arrAfter[$currKey] = array($currDate['end']);
            }
        }
    }
}

//sort the arrays
ksort($arrBefore);
krsort($arrAfter);

//sort sub-arrays
foreach($arrBefore as $subArr){
asort($subArr); 
}
//sort sub-arrays
foreach($arrAfter as $subArr){
rsort($subArr); 
}

print_r($arrBefore);

print_r($arrAfter);
```

Prints:

```
Array ( [2016-05-24] => Array ( [0] => 1464086700 ) [2016-05-27] => Array ( [0] => 1464349500 ) [2016-05-30] => Array ( [0] => 1464606900 [1] => 1464614100 ) ) 
Array ( [2016-05-31] => Array ( [0] => 1464705900 ) [2016-05-30] => Array ( [0] => 1464623100 ) )


?>
```

Comment: There is a problem with array_merge, because it overwrites keys. Please see the description of my attempt that I added to my post. How do I need to adapt my code?

Answer (score 0):

Do what you have tried, and simply `add` these arrays, that will keep your keys:

```
$desiredFinalArrDates  = $future + $past;
```